# Bind9 reverese look up error with CNAME and 192

Tags: bind

I'm trying to configure my bind9 resolution file to take in CNAME and a reverse ipv4 of 192.168.1.112 but everytime i add them it just doesn't work as it shows in the video tutorials

> This is my zone  file

```
zone "localhost" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/db.local112.zone";
```

---

> This is the db.local112.zone

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA example.com. root.example.email.com. (
             11     ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL

IN  NS  example.com.
IN  A   192.168.1.12
IN  A   192.168.1.13
```

This works fine and outputs the 2 address's listed but this next file outputs nothing, i would like to add an email, CNAME and reverse look up successfully

> This is my db.local11.zone re-configured

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.example.com. root.localhost. (
                        111         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

    IN      NS      example.com.
    IN      A       192.168.1.12
    IN      A       192.168.1.13

ns    IN    A       192.168.1.12

exampleXYZ.com.        IN      CNAME   exampleXYZ.com.
exampleXYZ.com.        IN      A       192.168.1.112


12.      IN     PTR      exampleXYZ.com.

smtp                   IN      A               192.168.10.1
                       IN      MX              10   smtp
```

After a **service bin9 reload** i can still use dig on the example.com but not on dig exampleXYZ.com or dig 192.168.1.112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of fundamental flaws in here, I'm afraid.

1. Incorrect zone name:

   ```
   zone "localhost" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/db.local112.zone";
   };
   ```

   The zone name should not be "localhost". Instead, it should be the actual name of your zone (i.e. "example.com").
2. Improper use of `CNAME`:

   ```
   exampleXYZ.com.        IN      CNAME   exampleXYZ.com.
   exampleXYZ.com.        IN      A       192.168.1.112
   ```

   First, you have a CNAME which loops back to itself.
   Second, you cannot mix a CNAME withy any other record set for the same label. For `exampleXYZ.com.`, you can have either an A record, or a CNAME, but not both.
3. You seem to be mixing data for `exampleXYZ.com.` into the same zone as `example.com`. You cannot do this.
4. You are attempting to put reverse (PTR) records into a forward lookup zone. You cannot do this either. If you want to host reverse lookup records, they need to be in their own zone, such as `zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa"`.

If you are serious about managing your own DNS server, I strongly recommend [O'Reilly's DNS & BIND](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100574) , which is a fine book on the subject.